# Modelica: when initial print only once

Tags: initialization, modelica, dymola, utilities

I have the following Modelica code, inside a component that is used several times in a system model:

```
parameter fileName = "world.log"
equation  
  when initial() then
    if not Modelica.Utilities.Files.exist(fileName) then
      Streams.print("Hello World", fileName);
    end if;
  end when;
```

I would expect to find exactly one line of code in the created file, but instead there are usually 5 or more lines printed, but sometimes it seems to work as expected. Using Dymola 2019 on Windows 10. 
Can someone clarify what is going on? The file existance check seems to be unreliable!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`when initial()` is not related to events at all. It is transformed into an initial equation and may thus execute multiple times. External objects are much more reliable when it comes to executing equations only once.

Comment: That already helps, thanks. Could something like `when time == 0 then` work? And wht is wrong with the existance check?

Comment: The existence check I don't know what the problem is. But if you are simply referring to a file world.log in the package itself, I think the simulation won't look for it in that place (the simulation might run in a temporary directory somewhere and you should use `modelica://` URIs and load the path at runtime). Perhaps `when time > startTime` would work (although that variable does not exist and the start-time is usually not known...) `== 0` will not work because there won't be a positive edge since `time==0` during the initial step, but then you won't get the function to run during init.

Comment: Probably it makes more sense to use `when time >= startTime`? According to the Modelica spec 3.4 page 99, and indicated through warnings displayed by Dymola, only `>=` and and `<` generate time events. To me a time event seems more efficient and reliable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers and comments, the following seems to work:

```
parameter fileName = "world.log"
protected 
Modelica.SIunits.Time startTime;

equation  
  when initial() then
    startTime := time;
  end when; 
  when time >= startTime then
    if not Modelica.Utilities.Files.exist(fileName) then
      Streams.print("Hello World", fileName);
    end if;
  end when;
```